# How to change the focused hint color(upper) of TextInputLayout according to specific conditions programmatically

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

If the text entered in TextInputLayout meets the email regular expression, I would like to change the color of the hint label shown in the attached picture as programmatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setHintTextColor` function of the `TextInputLayout` to programatically change the hint color according to your preference.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);  

int colorInt = getResources().getColor(R.color.red,getTheme());
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(colorInt);

textInputLayout.setHintTextColor(colorStateList);
```

This will change the hint label color like this :

[image: TextInputLayout]